# iOS 9.3 update adds a passcode

Tags: ipad, ios

I just updated my iPad to iOS 9.3 today, and when it starts up it shows the 'slide to update", when I slide it requires me to enter my 4 digit passcode.  I never added a passcode, and now I have no access to my iPad.  Is this a known issue, or is this just me?  I can't find anything online about this.

I tried to change the password through iCloud.com, but the iPad isn't and won't connect to the internet.  <del>I am about to try to restore through iTunes, but by what I remember you cannot restore without unlocking your device.  But before I try to restore, is there a way to change your password with the device locked?  I do have an iTunes account on the iPad (or at least there was an account on there, maybe the update logged me out).</del> I just restored my iPad via DFU mode, so I don't need to change the passcode anymore.

So my 2 questions:

- Is this a known issue/what happened?
- <del>Can I change the password?</del>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there was a known issues, which is fixed with latest 9.3 update.

> Updating some iOS devices (iPhone 5s and earlier and iPad Air and earlier) to iOS 9.3 can require entering the Apple ID and password used to set up the device in order to complete the software update. In some cases, if customers do not recall their password, their device will remain in an inactivated state until they can recover or reset their password. For these older devices, we have temporarily pulled back the update and will release an updated version of iOS 9.3 in the next few days that does not require this step.”

Comment: But with that issue, it asks for an iTunes password.  Mine did not ask for an iTunes password, but a 4 digit number passcode.  I have never set one up on my iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find much about it, but wanted to add another data point — this just happened to a friend of mine. Regular restore mode didn't work, we had to go into DFU mode and restore from there.